# How can I customise the Animation of an Angle change in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

I have an app that shows a bunch of people who each have an origin and angle.

```
struct Location {
    var centre:CGPoint
    var facing:Angle
}
```

SwiftUI magically and automatically does a lot of the animation as they move from location A to location B

```
withAnimation {
    person.location = newLocation
}
```

However - for the Angle (facing) property, I want the animation to go in the shortest route (bearing in mind that in the real world - angles wrap around).

e.g. Swift UI correctly animates when the angle changes 5 -> 10 (degrees)

```
5,6,7,8,9,10
```

but going from 2 to 358, it takes the long way around

SwiftUI does 2,3,4,5,6,7.......,357,358

where I would like it to do

```
2,1,0,359,358
```

how can I go about this?

thank you

update: I'm hoping for a solution which allows me to work with the animation system, perhaps using a new MyAngle struct which provides the animation steps directly, perhaps using some kind of animation modifier.
.easeInOut modifies the steps - is there an equivalent approach where I can create a .goTheRightWay animation?

Answer (score 3):

Ok - Posting my own answer.
It works a bit like @Ben's answer - but moves the 'shadow angle' management to the rotation effect.

All you have to do is switch `rotationEffect(angle:Angle)` for `shortRotationEffect(angle:Angle,id:UUID)`

this looks like

```
        @State private var rotationStorage = RotationStorage()

        //and then in body
        Image(systemName: "person.fill").resizable()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .shortRotationEffect(self.person.angle,id:person.id,storage:rotationStorage)
            .animation(.easeInOut)
```

the ShortRotationEffect uses the provided id to maintain a dictionary of previous angles. When you set a new angle, it figures out the equivalent angle which provides a short rotation and applies that with a normal `rotationEffect(...)`

Here it is:

```
class RotationStorage {
    private var storage: [UUID: Angle] = [:]
    
    fileprivate func setAngle(id:UUID,angle:Angle) {
        storage[id] = angle
    }
    
    fileprivate func getAngle(_ id:UUID) -> Angle? {
        return storage[id]
    }
}

extension View {

    /// Like RotationEffect - but when animated, the rotation moves in the shortest direction.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - angle: new angle
    ///   - anchor: anchor point
    ///   - id: unique id for the item being displayed. This is used as a key to maintain the rotation history and figure out the right direction to move
    func shortRotationEffect(_ angle: Angle,
                             anchor: UnitPoint = .center,
                             id: UUID,
                             storage:RotationStorage) -> some View {
        
        modifier(ShortRotation(angle: angle,
                               anchor: anchor,
                               id: id,
                               storage:storage))
    }
}

struct ShortRotation: ViewModifier {
    
    var angle: Angle
    var anchor: UnitPoint
    var id: UUID
    let storage:RotationStorage
    

    func getAngle() -> Angle {
        var newAngle = angle

        if let lastAngle = storage.getAngle(id) {
            let change: Double = (newAngle.degrees - lastAngle.degrees) %% 360.double

            if change < 180 {
                newAngle = lastAngle + Angle.init(degrees: change)
            } else {
                newAngle = lastAngle + Angle.init(degrees: change - 360)
            }
        }

        storage.setAngle(id: id, angle: newAngle)

        return newAngle
    }


    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .rotationEffect(getAngle(), anchor: anchor)
    }
}
```

this relies on my positive modulus function:

```
public extension Double {
    
    /// Returns modulus, but forces it to be positive
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - left: number
    ///   - right: modulus
    /// - Returns: positive modulus
    static  func %% (_ left: Double, _ right: Double) -> Double {
        let truncatingRemainder = left.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: right)
        return truncatingRemainder >= 0 ? truncatingRemainder : truncatingRemainder+abs(right)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is better, but doesn't quite work. When I rotate in a complete circle, it still jumps at the end of the 360 deg rotation. This does solve the jump that was happening between 0 and 360, though.

Comment: @DominicHolmes - not sure why you're seeing that. I have been using this in production for years now without any jumps...

Answer (score 1):

How about adjusting the newLocation value to keep within 180˚ of the start? Here's a function to check if the distance animated is greater than half way around and provide a new endpoint that satisfies it.

```
func adjustedEnd(from start: CGFloat, to target: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

    // Shift end to be greater than start
    var end = target
    while end < start { end += 360 }

    // Mod the distance with 360, shifting by 180 to keep on the same side of a circle
    return (end - start + 180).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360) - 180 + start
}
```

Some sample test cases:

```
let startValues: [CGFloat] = [2, -10, 345, 365, 700]
let endValues: [CGFloat] = [2, 10, 180, 185, 350, -10, 715, -700]
for start in startValues {
    print("From \(start):")
    for end in endValues {
        let adjusted = adjustedEnd(from: start, to: end)
        print("\t\(end) \tbecomes \(adjusted);\tdistance \(abs(adjusted - start))")
    }
}
```

prints the following:

```
From 2.0:
    2.0     becomes 2.0;    distance 0.0
    10.0    becomes 10.0;   distance 8.0
    180.0   becomes 180.0;  distance 178.0
    185.0   becomes -175.0; distance 177.0
    350.0   becomes -10.0;  distance 12.0
    -10.0   becomes -10.0;  distance 12.0
    715.0   becomes -5.0;   distance 7.0
    -700.0  becomes 20.0;   distance 18.0
From -10.0:
    2.0     becomes 2.0;    distance 12.0
    10.0    becomes 10.0;   distance 20.0
    180.0   becomes -180.0; distance 170.0
    185.0   becomes -175.0; distance 165.0
    350.0   becomes -10.0;  distance 0.0
    -10.0   becomes -10.0;  distance 0.0
    715.0   becomes -5.0;   distance 5.0
    -700.0  becomes 20.0;   distance 30.0
From 345.0:
    2.0     becomes 362.0;  distance 17.0
    10.0    becomes 370.0;  distance 25.0
    180.0   becomes 180.0;  distance 165.0
    185.0   becomes 185.0;  distance 160.0
    350.0   becomes 350.0;  distance 5.0
    -10.0   becomes 350.0;  distance 5.0
    715.0   becomes 355.0;  distance 10.0
    -700.0  becomes 380.0;  distance 35.0
From 365.0:
    2.0     becomes 362.0;  distance 3.0
    10.0    becomes 370.0;  distance 5.0
    180.0   becomes 540.0;  distance 175.0
    185.0   becomes 185.0;  distance 180.0
    350.0   becomes 350.0;  distance 15.0
    -10.0   becomes 350.0;  distance 15.0
    715.0   becomes 355.0;  distance 10.0
    -700.0  becomes 380.0;  distance 15.0
From 700.0:
    2.0     becomes 722.0;  distance 22.0
    10.0    becomes 730.0;  distance 30.0
    180.0   becomes 540.0;  distance 160.0
    185.0   becomes 545.0;  distance 155.0
    350.0   becomes 710.0;  distance 10.0
    -10.0   becomes 710.0;  distance 10.0
    715.0   becomes 715.0;  distance 15.0
    -700.0  becomes 740.0;  distance 40.0
```

(Edited to account for negative ending values)

**Edit:** From your comment about keeping a second value around, what about setting `Location.facing` to the adjusted angle, and then adding to Location something like

```
var prettyFacing: Angle {
    var facing = self.facing
    while facing.degrees < 0 { facing += Angle(degrees: 360) }
    while facing.degrees > 360 { facing -= Angle(degrees: 360) }
    return facing
}
```

Comment: thanks for chiming in. I have considered that approach - but it requires maintaining a set of shadow locations which have to be adjusted as you change the actual location. I'm hoping for a way that I can change the animation logic directly.
Somewhere in the animation system - there must something which is figuring out the steps between A and B...

Comment: Ah I see @ConfusedVorlon. Does the person model need to keep an angle value between 0 and 360? What if the location.facing was set to this adjusted value, and then you added a computed variable to `Location`, something like `prettyFacing` that adjusts `facing` back to non-negative if necessary?

Comment: Answer edited to with example. Still not helpful about the animation question I realize, just thought maybe it could be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

After trying both of the other options, we were still getting visual glitches (less common, but still there!).

#### Our Solution: Use UIKit for Animation

We've created a SPM package that adds a simple modifier, `.uiRotationEffect()`. This modifier wraps your `View` in a `UIView`, and uses `UIView`'s `.animate(...)` function to get the correct behavior.

You can install the package [here](https://github.com/DominicHolmes/UIRotationEffect) or you can just copy and paste the code [here](https://github.com/DominicHolmes/UIRotationEffect/blob/master/Sources/UIRotationEffect/UIRotationEffect.swift), it's not very long.

GIF of the working solution:

[image]

Comment: I think this is a great solution and works well! However, when used within a Geometry Reader, it appears the anchor point is off center. Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

**withAnimation in SwiftUI**

The above method won't work if using `withAnimation` in SwiftUI.
I managed to find a workaround as follows, to avoid animation 'pop back' when crossing the 360/0 limit, we set the value of the angle to 0 (or 360) directly to avoid animating, then the next animation will just fix the behaviour:

Super greedy, but it works, and the cut is not really noticeable

```swift
        private func onDragGesture(value: DragGesture.Value, centerX: Double, centerY: Double) {
        let current = value.location
        
        // calculate difference in angle based on gesture
        var theta = (atan2(current.x - centerX, centerY - current.y) - atan2(value.startLocation.x - centerX, centerY - value.startLocation.y)) * 180.0 / Double.pi
        
        if (theta < 0) { theta += 360 }
        if(self.angle > 330 && self.lastAngle + theta < 30) {
            self.angle = 0
        } else if (self.angle < 30 && self.lastAngle + theta > 330) {
            self.angle = 360
        }else{
            withAnimation{
                self.angle = theta + self.lastAngle
            }
        }
    }
```